# kernel size for upscore layer in caffe implementation for fully convolutional neural network

Tags: computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe

I am trying to understand the `caffe` implementation of [Fully Convolutional Networks for Semantic Segmentation](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jonlong/long_shelhamer_fcn.pdf)
. For its upscore layer implementation in [fcn32 model](https://github.com/shelhamer/fcn.berkeleyvision.org/blob/master/voc-fcn32s/net.py), it sets up `kernel_size=64`. when reading the original paper, I did not find the description of this setup, What’s the reason that we need to setup `kernel_size=64`?

```
n.fc6, n.relu6 = conv_relu(n.pool5, 4096, ks=7, pad=0)
n.drop6 = L.Dropout(n.relu6, dropout_ratio=0.5, in_place=True)
n.fc7, n.relu7 = conv_relu(n.drop6, 4096, ks=1, pad=0)
n.drop7 = L.Dropout(n.relu7, dropout_ratio=0.5, in_place=True)
n.score_fr = L.Convolution(n.drop7, num_output=21, kernel_size=1, pad=0,
    param=[dict(lr_mult=1, decay_mult=1), dict(lr_mult=2, decay_mult=0)])
n.upscore = L.Deconvolution(n.score_fr,
    convolution_param=dict(num_output=21, kernel_size=64, stride=32,
        bias_term=False),
    param=[dict(lr_mult=0)])
n.score = crop(n.upscore, n.data)
n.loss = L.SoftmaxWithLoss(n.score, n.label,
        loss_param=dict(normalize=False, ignore_label=255))
```

Comment: please do not post screen shots of code/log/terminal outputs, but rather copy-paste the text (with proper formatting). search engines cannot index text in screenshots.